# Google Chrome extension - stop loading website after loading a single div

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [ 
   {
      "matches": ["https://somepage.com"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } 
],
```

content.js

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.stop();
}, 10);
```

I have this, but it's bad, because somebody who have faster connection it will won't work for him.
We have some page, with three divs: logo, page-content, footer, and I want to interrupt loading website when the page-content is already loaded and it will load only two divs: logo and page-content.

Comment: For clarity, it will or won't work for him?

Comment: won't, sorry for my grammar, i know that she is bad

Comment: Use MutationObserver instead of setTimeout.